# function not working to convert html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if someone can spot the mistake in my code?

javascript:

```
function decodehtml(thestring){
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html(thestring).text();
    alert(decoded);
    return decoded;
}
```

inside html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
decodehtml("test&#32;string");
</script>
```

I know it is both returning and alerting, the alert is in there just for the test. For some reason this is doing nothing.

Any ideas?
Simon

Edit:

Even placing this directly into the html does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var decoded = $("<div/>").html("test&#32;string").text();
alert(decoded);
</script>
```

Comment: I am doing a wild guess here: The function is not declared before you call it?

Comment: You're calling the function, but not doing anything with the returned value. Assign it to a variable, and then *use* that variable somewhere.

Comment: I am calling the function before so not that problem, and I am alerting just for a test, the alert does not even show

Comment: Can you post a bit more code?

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: I just grabbed this function straight off stackoverflow, it had 200+ upvotes so I kind of trusted it. This is all the code I am writing for this function, I am trying to pass a string in with html encoded characters and have it returned without the html encoded charecters

Comment: Your code is working, check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/gNQXM/ ensure you are not getting error and jQuery is included.

Comment: I guess you are not including the jQuery script.

Comment: When manually placing my edit into the code I am getting:
"$ is not defined"

Comment: Okay jquery is working, but I am running this inside a search script, possibly that making it not work

Comment: Can you post some of your HTML though? Cause you're selecting `$("<div/>")` and maybe this would work a little better: `$("div")` what are you trying to select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function decodehtml(thestring) {
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html(thestring).text();
    alert(decoded);
    return decoded;
}

decodehtml("stuff");
```

Seems to work fine. Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/MnVQJ/)

Comment: And there was necessity for an answer for this? It is already been said in the comments

Comment: on a side note: **</div>** instead of **<div/>** for a closing **div**

Comment: In jQuery that syntax is used to let the constructor know that it has to create a new element

Comment: Ok... Someone please can explain why an answer saying "this actually works" is accepted ? "_I've got a problem, this does not works ! _Actually this does works... _Ok thanks ! Bye" o_o

Comment: @Brewal This made me laugh out loud! So funny!

Answer (score 0):

> $ is not defined

This means you are not including jQuery. Place this in your head tag :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

And then put your code.